# Continuous Markov Chain probability of states

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

Prince Charming is coming to rescue Sleeping Beauty (SB) from her slumbering imprisonment with a kiss. However, SB sleeps in one of three positions:
State 0: flat on her back, in which case she looks truly radiant;
State 1: foetal position, in which case she looks less than radiant;
State 2: foetal position and sucking her thumb, in which case she does not look
radiant at all.
Changes of position occur according to a Markov Chain with transition matrix

P = $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0.75 & 0.25 \\
0.25 & 0 & 0.75 \\
0.25 & 0.75 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$v_0 = 1/2$,
$v_1 = 1/3$
$v_2 = 1$
What is the probability that Prince Charming finds SB looking truly radiant at the time he arrives? Naturally, SB has been sleeping for a very long time.

I started this question by finding the matrix G instead as it's continuous time and found

G = $\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} \\
\frac{1}{12} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

However, I'm not sure how to finish the question from here, am I looking for $P_{00}(t) + P_{10}(t) + P_{20}(t)$ to find the total probabilities? If so how do I actually find all those? Just looking for some guidance to understand the next step or if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: I think they are asking you to find the stationary distribution (row eigenvector of $P$ corresponding to eigenvalue $1$).

Comment: I'm lost on what you mean by eigenvector and eigenvalue? I've never used any of those in statistics

Comment: There is nothing about continuous time in the exercise and your invocation of a generator matrix G is offtopic. Stationary distributions $\pi$ of a Markov chain in discrete time with transition matrix $P$ solve $\pi=\pi P$. Your job is to solve this.

Comment: It's continuous time because I was given the $v_0$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ which are the rates at which it leaves the states, 0,1 and 2, which are in use for continuous time.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out. I was on the right track the $G$ matrix, however the $P(t)$'s did not matter and should have focused on $\pi_0$ which is solved using the system of equations from $\pi G=0$ where we get

$-\frac{1}{2}\pi_0 + \frac{1}{12}\pi_1 + \frac{1}{4}\pi_2 = 0$

$\frac{3}{8}\pi_0 + -\frac{1}{3}\pi_1 + \frac{3}{4}\pi_2 = 0$

$\frac{1}{8}\pi_0 + \frac{1}{4}\pi_1 + -\pi_2 = 0$

$\pi_0 + \pi_1 + \pi_2 = 1$

solving and subsituting we get $\pi_0$ = 0.1944